# How to generate a random amount of key name?

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences

So I'm trying to make a program which shows you a word and if you click the button, it shows its definition. And first, I'm trying to make it work by adding the word/definition using getSharedPrefrences

```
private void savePrefrences(){
                SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putString("", "");
                editor.commit();
            }
```

, but you need key name in the `editor.putString("Key name Here","word/definition here")`to store the thing inside the key. But I don't know how to generate random amount of key names.

HELP ME FAST!!

Comment: Why do you think you need shared preferences here?  Where are you storing all the words for the app to use?  I think you'd probably want to store them using something like SQLite, not shared prefs.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm pretty newbie so I'm trying to use the most simple thing. And I don't really have that much time to learn something really new, so can you help me with the original question?

Comment: I can't help, because I don't know what the source of the words (or definitions) is, and you never told us this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the source would be the user, so I would put editText and get definition and word from the user, then save it to individual keys.